# AngularJS datepicker change day item CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, datepicker

I'd like to use the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker.

Also, I have e.g. a the Events list for, let's say - 12th January

Is it possible to change e.g. the color of that day in the datepicker that I can see that for that day some events exist ?

the reason is, I'd like to give the opportunity for users to be aware whose days contains any Events

Comment: I think that you could override the default template and add a class if some conditiont is met.
If you provide your code or an example in a fiddle or something maybe I can try to give you an example

Answer (score 0):

I've found that plugin https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker (in the demo, set the 'multidate' textbox value to true).

Moreover, that plugin offers the method to select many dates.

That's exactly I was looking for